# Django - is using proxy model for users recommended?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Currently, I'm using a couple of proxy model for differentiating different users in the admin site.

```
class TeacherProxy(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
        app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name = 'Teacher'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Teachers'

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #inlines = [TeacherClassInline]
    def queryset(self,request):
        return User.objects.filter(groups__name='Teachers')
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "groups":
            qs = Group.objects.filter(name='Teachers')
            kwargs["queryset"] = qs
            kwargs["initial"] = qs
        return super(TeacherAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(TeacherProxy,TeacherAdmin)
```

However, I realized that a couple of things break if I use this method:

1. doesn't allow me to add
   tabularInlines for foreign key
   relationships because Django
   complained of absence of foreign key
   for userproxy.
2. Urls are messed up. Django will
   register
   `http://abc.com/admin/auth/teacherproxy/`
   instead of
   `http://abc.com/admin/auth/user/`
   and Django will not find a Teacher
   object.

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Django likes you to extend the User model their way by adding a user profile. Here are their docs for how to do this:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles

You could then add a field in each user's profile to designate if they are a Teacher or not.

Personally, I find it easier to just use Django the way the docs suggest you use it because then you know everything works. Plus it will be easier to find support from others if things break in the future. Thus, I'd go with adding a profile class to extend the user model the way they say.

Comment: am doing that. Just that in the admin site, I want to separate the users visually so that I can apply my own admin class.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry I totally misread your question. Unfortunately I'm not too experienced in beefing up the admin interface...

Answer (score 2):

Django supports inlining models that have foreignkeys to a parent class.  See this bug:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7918

On top of Django model inheritance, you are using a Proxy Model which is supposed to be a transparent passthrough to the model it references.  I also found that it doesn't work quite right and complains about not have a foreignkey to the right model.

One solution is to use a Django generic relation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

Instead of having a foreignkey to the parent class, you add these fields to your model:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Django can now have a foreignkey to any other model in your app.  It actually stores the id of the object it is pointing to along with the type of object (the content_type).  Be aware that every time you follow the foreignkey relationship, django must do an extra lookup in the content_types table to figure out which model the generic relation is actually pointing to.